# Is it a good practice to cast from an interface to some concrete class when needed?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I'am developing a small system and i developed the classic generic repository. For now, i have the following architecture for my DAL.

```
public interface IRepositorio<T> where T : class
{
    T Get(long id);
    long Insert(T obj);
    bool Update(T obj);
    bool Delete(T obj);
}

public abstract class Repositorio<T> : IRepositorio<T> where T : class
{
    public IDbConnection Connection
    {
        get
        {
            return new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBFila"].ConnectionString);
        }
    }

    public T Get(long id)
    {
        //...
    }

    public long Insert(T obj)
    {
        //...
    }

    public bool Update(T obj)
    {
        //...
    }

    public bool Delete(T obj)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

My concrete repository looks like this:

```
public class FilaRepositorio : Repositorio<FilaRepositorio>
{
    public FilaRepositorio() 
    {
    }

    public void SomeCustomMethod()
    {
        // Some custom method
    }
}
```

I am also using Simple Injector to follow the IoC and DI patterns, for this reason, when i try to call "SomeCustomMethod()" i dont have access to it (obviously). Look:

```
public class Processador
{
    private IRepositorio<FilaModel> _repoFila;
    public Processador(IRepositorio<FilaModel> repoFila)
    {
        _repoFila = repoFila;
    }

    public void Processar()
    {
        _repoFila.SomeCustomMethod(); // <-- wrong

        ((FilaRepositorio)_repoFila).SomeCustomMethod();// <-- works
    }
}
```

Given this i have some questions:

- Is a good or acceptable practice to make that cast (FilaRepositorio)?
- If its not a good practice, how to write good code for this case?

Comment: As both answers already described, casting from the interface back to the implementation is a bad idea. If you do this, there is absolutely no reason to have this interface anymore. More generally, if your code depends on a concrete type, you are violating the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) that states that classes should depend on abstractions. Furthermore, explicitly casting the interface to such concrete type is a violation of the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: IMO, I don't think that this question is "primarily opinion-based" and it should therefore _not_ be closed. The literature and common design principles are very clear on this, so the question can actually be answered quite objectively by referencing to literature (as I did in my previous comment).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few options available. The main problem with making the cast is that it is an implementation concern.

What would happen if the injected object was not a `FilaRepositorio`?

By making the cast you are tightly coupling the class to an implementation concern that is not guaranteed to be the inject dependency. Thus the constructor is not being entirely truthful about what it needs to perform its function.

This demonstrates the need to practice [Explicit Dependencies Principle](http://deviq.com/explicit-dependencies-principle/)

> **The Explicit Dependencies Principle states:**
>
> Methods and classes should explicitly require (typically through
>   method parameters or constructor parameters) any collaborating objects
>   they need in order to function correctly.

One way to avoid it would be to make a derived interface that explicitly exposes the desired functionality of its dependents.

```
public interface IFilaRepositorio : IRepositorio<FilaModel> {
    void SomeCustomMethod();
}

public class FilaRepositorio : Repositorio<FilaModel>, IFilaRepositorio {
    public void SomeCustomMethod() {
        //...other code removed for brevity.
    }
}
```

and have the `Processador` depend on that more targeted abstraction.

Now there is no need for the cast at all and the class explicitly expresses what it needs.

```
public class Processador {
    private readonly IFilaRepositorio _repoFila;

    public Processador(IFilaRepositorio  repoFila) {
        _repoFila = repoFila;
    }

    public void Processar() {
        _repoFila.SomeCustomMethod(); // <-- works
    }
}
```

Comment: But what if In Visual studio I would like to navigate to the concrete implementation. It becomes a nightmare when a lot of classes uses the same interface.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to access a specific method from any part of your application, then that specific method must be part of your abstraction, or else there is no guarantee that you may use it when changing the concrete class.

I do not believe that your use of casting is a good idea at all, what is usually done in this case is to create a specific interface which defines any other method you could need to use:

```
public interface IFilaRepositorio : IRepositorio<Fila>
{
     void SomeCustomMethod();
}
```

And than use and declare that specific interface in any part of your code where you believe you need to use it:

```
public class Processador
{
    private IFilaRepositorio _repoFila;
    public Processador(IFilaRepositorio  repoFila)
    {
        _repoFila = repoFila;
    }

    public void Processar()
    {
        _repoFila.SomeCustomMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of creating one-to-one interfaces for repositories, like the `IFilaRepositorio` interface, also take a look at more SOLID approaches like [this](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) and [this](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92).

Comment: Thank @Steven i learn o lot with your answers here in S.O. My next question would be: Is right to create one interface for each concrete type? But i think your comment answers this.

Comment: @Ewerton that's not a black or white answer. The bigger the application, thenmore likely it is that you get very common concepts (like queries, use cases, validation, etc) that youncan define that deserve their own abstraction that is used by the whole concept. So I would say that you would typically reuse abstractions. That would lead to the best maintainability

Comment: As always I appreciate your precious comment, @Steven. It's good to see abstract concepts implemented in a useful way.